# Is it possible to use Google Fonts in a Spring MVC JSP file?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, google-fonts

I have tried including the link to the stylesheet in the head of the JSP file as well as trying the @import option in my project stylesheet. Nothing has worked. I also haven't been able to find a webjar or any such thing.

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Boogaloo');

body {
    font-family: 'Boogaloo', cursive;
}
```

JSPF:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Boogaloo" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>HappyLibs Emailer</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Yes, I do this quite often.  You should probably include code example so we can help debug.

Comment: @Mostfoolish, code is added.

Comment: the c:url + the double-quotes doesn't look right -might want to try single quotes around the value.  I would try to confirm the main.css is being loaded via the developer tools (I happen to generally use Chrome -but whatever tools you're using can confirm that).

Comment: btw -are you normally able to load the css from that location?

Comment: The other styles I have in the stylesheet that I didn't include in the code example are working, so the stylesheet seems to be included. And this is my first spring app, so I don't have a "normal" for how I do this :p I'd love to know if there is a more conventional way, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue - it was actually caused by the order of the links in my head. I needed my CSS to be applied after the Bootstrap link so that my styles wouldn't be overridden:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Boogaloo" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <title>HappyLibs Emailer</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything special about Spring MVC or JSP in regards to using a Google Font.

In my experience, the external files (like css, javascript, and images) usually go in either the WebContent folder (standard build), or the webapp folder (maven build).

I don't believe the c:url tag is necessary for this.

**Standard Example**: *[root]/WebContent/[whatever folder structure makes sense]/main.css*

**MVN Example**: *src/main/webapp/[whatever folder structure makes sense]/main.css*

*I happen to like the structure like -> /view/page/[specific page]/[files]*

**Then, in the JSP:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
     <head>
          ...
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Boogaloo" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="view/main.css" rel="stylesheet" >
          ...
     </head>
     <body>
          ...
     </body>
</html>
```

Also, the browser's developer tools should show an error if it can't find a file in the specified location.

Chrome developer tools (ie: right-click on the page and choose 'inspect'): 
The console tab will show an error if it can't find it. The Sources tab will show you the files your page actually loaded.  The Elements tab will specify the styles being applied to the element in question -> to make sure something else isn't simply overriding the style you're expecting.